# Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function in Angular v6

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, runtime-error, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This error occurs after deploying the application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The build and deployment are successful and all the modules are working properly except for one which is displaying the above error of Super Expression. Everything seems to work properly on the local machine and the same module is even accessible on localhost but after deploying on AWS, the above error pops up. Any fix for the same?

Image of the error in the console for the module which is not accessible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We faced something similar recently, since we're facing an issue while routing to a module, we simply modified the `angular.json` and reset the optimization i.e. `"optimization" : false` and it worked for us.

Reference : https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/issues/381